# Python exit from all function and stop the execution

Tags: python, break

I'm trying to develop a script that will connect to our switch and do some tasks.
In this script I have a main function that calls a second function. In the second function I pass a list of switches that Python will start to connect one by one.
The second function will call a third function. In the third function the script makes some tests. If one of these tests fail I want to close the entire script.
The problem is that I tried to put `return`, `exit`, `raise System`, `os.exit` but what happens is that the script doesn't stop, it just jumps to another switch and goes on.

Anyone knows how can I close my entire script from a function?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
 import sys
 sys.exit()
```

or

```
raise SystemExit()
```

The parameters can be used to pass messages. If you are also dealing with loops, break also works really well.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.exit). `sys.exit()` will raise a `SystemExit` exception and close the program.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply.

I already tried use sys.exit, raise and others into the third funcion but nothing works. What I did, I put a return with stantement pass or fail. On the secund function I test the return and if fail the script execute sys.exit(). When I do this on the secund function the script stop like we want. Now it's working fine. Probably this is the worst way to do this but worked.

Best regards.